# jQuery mobile table color

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am looping through a list, and and would like to add color to the background of a cell in a table:

```
$("<td>")
   .addClass("tableCell")
   .text(cellText)
   .data("col", c)
   .appendTo(MyTable)
   .css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
```

But setting css do not work, any idea?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Works for me. Maybe some css "!important" rule overrides the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem before, changing

`.css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");`
to
`.css("background-color", "grey");`

seemed to work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Check out my jsFiddle, this works for me

I used `$("td")` instead of `$("<td>");`

http://jsfiddle.net/brSET/